How to replace a for example #test symbol in one method?
I would like to use Pharo GUI to replace a symbol #test within one method.  How do you do that?  I could not find a tool to use that for.
For example:
overview

send: #test
sendSecond: #test

I would like to have it changed to:
overview

send: #production
sendSecond: #production

How to do that within Pharo?

I found it today by accident.

In Pharo you have to have to right-click on the method's body.

In the pop-up menu you have to have to then select Find....

Now window appears that is called not Find but Find & Replace, where you can perform this simple search & replace.


I wish they could name it the pop-up menu so one can find it on first try.

In general, you use the code rewrite engine. You program the search using a combination of ast-node and regex string matching, find all the matching code, and apply the changes to the relevant matches

Yes, I'm using that (thank you for the suggestion), but for simple  change (e.g. one method) it is faster to do it via the Find dialog.
